# Making a Field Appear on Top of CSS Styling

Tags: css

Hello ive managed to create a star with css but it is hiding the field that i wat to show on front of the star. I was wondering if anyone coud point me i the right direction to what i should do to fix it. thanks

```
<div class="views-field views-field-field-freebetamount">
<div class="field-content">
<div id="star12">£200</div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.views-field-field-freebetamount {
color:white;
}

#star12 {
 background: blue;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 position: relative;

}

#star12:before, #star12:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 background: blue;
}

#star12:before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#star12:after {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

the freebetamount field should hopefully appear on top of the star. my limited css skills has lead me to try z-indexs but to no avail.

Anyone?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define the `negative z-index` value in `:before` and `:after` pseudo element.

```
#star12 {
 background: blue;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 position: relative;
   font-size:1.3em;
}

#star12:before, #star12:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 background: blue;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Check the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/hogixoca/1/)***.

Comment: your demo works fine Kheema but doe some reason not on my test website. i dont know if i able to add links to show you but you can see it in action here \9forgive the nae its ust an old url) http://islifeshit.com/casino

Comment: wish I could help you in real scenario.

Comment: can you pass the test URL link. so I can also look and help you.

Comment: sorry Kheema here it is here. http://islifeshit.com/casino i was away getting something to eat

Comment: bad luck I cannot see anything in the link. just some ads appear

Comment: lol they are the ads im trying to make. youll see the wee blue square with monetry valuesin them. thats whre the stars should be.

Comment: ps i dont even have affiliate links in the ads yet so its not as if 'im at it'.

Comment: can see the blue bg color with some amount.. but start is not completed. haven't you added the full style code?

Comment: i just copied all the code css from your example page Kheema (viewed source).I really appreciate your help. If its too much trouble just tell me to do it another way. I suppose i can live without stars :\

Comment: well the rotated div which is giving star look is not appearing in the url. but if you are okay with the current results than its fine.

Comment: may be you can close this answer by accepting the answer then. so it could be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

With css u need to set `z-index: 100` or something like that to place something on top of the others

Comment: everything sees to ork as expeced Grg its just the transformed bits that make up the star that have now dissapeared. Weird as Kheema's demo works perfect. Maybe i shold look into just using a star image behid the field poss.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to take a look at z-index.  Whichever element you want to appear on top of another needs to have a higher CSS z-index number.

in css file;

```
#yourID {
z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: a brilliant thanks for the repies chaps. Kheea your method works as hoped but it seems to remove all the star elements fro the css leaving e just a blue box (with my white text showing). adding the further suggsted z index to my .views-field-field-freebetamount doesnt seem to work either. Sorry for being such a fud :(